# Can someone explain the principle behind this simple code please?

Tags: php, mysql

Im having difficulty comprehending a line of code that i am using to retrieve results from a mysql database.

I connect to the database with

```
<?php
try
{
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=****', '****',
'****');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
$error = 'Unable to connect to the database server.' . $e->getMessage;
echo $error;
exit();
}
```

this is fine. the connection works.

to retrive the results i use this code....

```
$sql = 'SELECT joketext FROM joke';

$results = $pdo->query($sql);
```

this also is fine but then i use a foreach loop to loop through the result set as so...

```
foreach ($results as $result){
    $jokes[] = $result['joketext'];
}
```

and then another foreach to loop through $jokes as so...

```
foreach ($jokes as $joke) {
echo $joke;
}
```

now this all works it displays the joketext i wanted from the mysql table. However i dont understand the line...

```
$jokes[] = $result['joketext'];
```

does this means I am assigning the result set to an array? what does $jokes[]= mean? and why do i have to do this?

I thought i was retrieving strings of text from the database table. The table has an id, joketext, jokedate, and authorid as columns. But if im only selecting the joketext column surely that retrieves a list of all the joketext entries and therefore i can just loop through with a foreach echoing out the results?

Comment: `$array[] = $value` will append `$value` to the end of `$array`. In principle, it works the same as [`array_push()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

Comment: In your case, you don't need two `foreach` loops. You could just `echo $result['joketext'];`. The advantage of the `$jokes` array comes if you need to resort or otherwise further process the result prior to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your query only selects for one column `joketext` so you don't have any of the other column data in your result set.

Using `$jokes[] = ..` is a shorthand way of assigning a value to a new element in the `$jokes` array.  You don't necessarily need to do this.  It is just commonly done so that you can use the data later on, in multiple places if you want.  Alternatively, you can just work with the result set directly each time. That isn't as commonly done though since the result set is an object or resource that contains more than what you may actually need. But if you're just looking to output the joketext immediately, then you can skip putting it into a separate array and just `echo $result['joketext'];` in your first loop

Answer (score 2):

The `$jokes[]` syntax is appending the joke text string to the `$jokes` array. If the array doesn't exist, it will be created.

It's the same as doing:

```
array_push($jokes, $result['joketext']);
```

If you don't need to create a new array, you can just work with the joke text directly in the `$results` foreach, if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

`$jokes[] =` appends a new value to an array and is the same as doing `$jokes[count($jokes)]` (not completely correct but is a simple way of explaining it).

Technically, you don't **have** to put all the values in a new array, you could use the original loop instead.

`array_push` has the same functionality, you can read up about it [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then I believe you are correct. The second `foreach` is not needed, you can simply `echo` the `$result['joketext']` during the first `foreach` and skip the second one altogether.

so delete the second `foreach` and edit the first one as follows:

```
foreach ($results as $result){
    echo( $result['joketext'] );
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. In combination with the other answers its starting to make sense now.